# Why is it impossible to drop user despite it exists in dba_users view

Tags: oracle, exists

I try to drop/alter user like this

```
drop user AVASILIEV_AXIOM_10X
```

And I get the following error

```
SQL> drop user AVASILIEV_AXIOM_10X;
drop user AVASILIEV_AXIOM_10X
          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01918: user 'AVASILIEV_AXIOM_10X' does not exist
```

But this user exists in the dba_users view:

```
SQL> select username from dba_users where username='AVASILIEV_AXIOM_10X';

USERNAME
------------------------------
AVASILIEV_AXIOM_10X

SQL>
```

Also, I can't create user with the same name because it already exists in the DB. What's the problem?

My Oracle version:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.4.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

Comment: Can you see `AVASILIEV_AXIOM_10X` in the `ALL_USERS` view? If not, then `drop user` will not be able to find the user for you to drop.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Any user can see any other user in `ALL_USERS`, with no privileges.

Comment: @JonHeller That's not how I read the docs, but don't have an Oracle instance handy to test. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2114.htm#REFRN20302

Comment: @ShannonSeverance I tested it on 12c and just granting `create session` was enough for a user to see all other users.  I'm not sure when a user would not be "visible" (as the manual says) to another user.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Yes, I can see this user in ALL_USERS view. What is more I can't drop it even being as SYSTEM user. I dropped it as SYS user with SYSDBA privileges! It's really strange...

Answer (score 4):

This is old thread but for reference Oracle Doc ID 1297361.1 suggests as follows:

```
SQL> drop user ahong3;
```

drop user ahong3
   *
ERROR at line 1:

```
ORA-01918: user 'AHONG3' does not exist

SQL> select username from dba_users where username='ahong3';

USERNAME
------------------------------
ahong3

SQL> execute hcheck.full
HCheck Version 8i-11/1.95

Found 0 potential problems and 0 warnings
```

`PL/SQL` procedure successfully completed.

**CAUSE**
User was created forcibly in lower case.  Drop user considers the user to be in upper case, and hence can't find it.

Ex: below statement will force the creation of the user in lower case.

```
SQL> Create user "ahong3";
```

**SOLUTION**
Force the drop `user statement` to drop the user created in lower case by specifying the user name in double quotes:

```
SQL> Drop user "ahong3";
```

This solution worked for me

Answer (score -1):

```
DROP USER user CASCADE;
```

Hope this work cz its work for me

Comment: The `cascade` option would only help if the error message was `ORA-01922: CASCADE must be specified to drop 'AVASILIEV_AXIOM_10X'`.